# Digital Signature, does it validate that a message has been sent by a host I trust via HTTP?

Tags: json, http, digital-signature

I have the following setup:

A remote host generates a key pair. He sends me his public key over a secure channel. I can 100% guarantee that the public key is sent from him. Then he uses that keypair to sign some data that are encoded in JSON format. He procceeds to do a POST Http request to me with two parameters:

a)The JSON string 
b)The signature generated from the JSON String.

On my end, when I receive the data, I use his public key and the signature he provided in the HTTP POST to verify.

Does this procedure guarantee that the message :

1)Is actually sent by the host the sender claims to be.
2)Is not altered by a man in the middle attack ?

Comment: Reinvent https client certificates why don't you.

Comment: If I could use SSL I would have, trust me ;)

Comment: Yes, this is how PKI works. What you can trust is the relationship between the public and the private key, and since only your trustee has the private key (the person in the middle does not) you can trust the message. But before you start building safeguards against replay attacks and stuff like that, please consider an existing mechanism. Homegrown security usually disappoints.

Comment: I had never heard about PKI before and it seems to be the same solution I gave to my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Technically, your solution is [asymmetric cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). The Infrastructure is there to provide the rest - safe key acquisition etc. Good work! Next time, invent something that doesn't exist, will you? :)

Answer (score 1):

> Does this procedure guarantee that the message is actually sent by the host the sender claims to be?

Technically, the answer is no.  But it may not matter because the answer to your next question:

> Does this procedure guarantee that the message is not altered by a man
>   in the middle attack?

is yes.

An untrusted host could send you a message signed by your trusted source.  They would only need to obtain or capture the message and signature.

If you're not using SSL, your connection to a trusted server is not guaranteed.  But as long as you verify the message being sent is signed by the private key corresponding to the public key you have, then the message is unaltered and you know it is from a trusted source.

So the worst case would be that an untrusted host sends you a copy of a trusted message.

This may or may not be OK for what you need.  If your messages are time or order dependent, then this could be a problem.  If they put your server into a particular state, that also might be a problem.